# Copy tables from one DB to anotherDB using spring batch

Tags: spring-batch

I need to copy tables from two different db to single db(destination DB).
 For Example,Table1 from DB1 and to Table1 in the DB3 and Table2 from DB2 to Table2 in the DB3. All the tables are sharing the same structure.

I've created three datasource and one reader

```
// Datasource Config

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "db3EntityManagerFactory",
    transactionManagerRef = "db3TransactionManager",
    basePackages = { "demo.sample.dao" })
public class Db3Config {

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "db3DataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create()
        .build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "db3EntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean db3EntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
        @Qualifier("db3DataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
    return builder.dataSource(dataSource)
        .packages("demo.sample.dao")
        .persistenceUnit("db3")
        .build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "db3TransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager db3TransactionManager(
        @Qualifier("db3EntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory db3EntityManagerFactory) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(db3EntityManagerFactory);
    }

}

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "db2EntityManagerFactory",
    transactionManagerRef = "db2TransactionManager",
    basePackages = { "demo.sample.dao" })
public class Db2Config {

    @Bean(name = "db2DataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "db2.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create()
        .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "db2EntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean db3EntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
        @Qualifier("db2DataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
    return builder.dataSource(dataSource)
        .packages("demo.sample.dao")
        .persistenceUnit("db2")
        .build();
    }


    @Bean(name = "db2TransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager db2TransactionManager(
        @Qualifier("db2EntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory db2EntityManagerFactory) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(db2EntityManagerFactory);
    }

}

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "db1EntityManagerFactory",
    transactionManagerRef = "db1TransactionManager",
    basePackages = { "demo.sample.dao" })
public class Db1Config {
    @Bean(name = "db1DataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "db1.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create()
        .build();
    }
     @Bean(name = "db1EntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean db1EntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
        @Qualifier("db1DataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
    return builder.dataSource(dataSource)
        .packages("demo.sample.dao")
        .persistenceUnit("db1")
        .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "db1TransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager db1TransactionManager(
        @Qualifier("db1EntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory db1EntityManagerFactory) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(db1EntityManagerFactory);
    }

}

-- Job Config

@Configuration
public class DBImportJob{

    @Autowired
    Db1Config db1Config ;

    @Autowired
    Db2Config db2Config ;

    @Autowired
    Db3Config db3Config ;

 @Bean(name = "DBImportJob")
    public Job dbImportJob(final JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory, final StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory) {


Step person1= stepBuilderFactory.get("Person1_FROM_DB1_TABLE")
        .<Person, Person>chunk(1000)
        .reader(personReader(db1Config.dataSource(),
            "select * from person"))
        .writer(writer(db3Config.dataSource(),
            "insert into person1"))
        .build();

    Step person2= stepBuilderFactory.get("Person2_FROM_DB2_TABLE")
        .<Person, Person>chunk(1000)
        .reader(personReader1(db2Config.dataSource(),
            "select * from person"))
        .writer(writer1(db3Config.dataSource(),
            "insert into person2"))     
            .build();


    return jobBuilderFactory.get("personImportJob")
        .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
        .start(person1)
        .next(person2)      
        .build();

    }

    @Bean
    JdbcCursorItemReader<Person> personReader(DataSource dataSource, String sql) {
    JdbcCursorItemReader<Person> databaseReader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
    databaseReader.setDataSource(dataSource);
    databaseReader.setSql(sql);
    databaseReader.setRowMapper(new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Person.class));
    return databaseReader;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person> writer(DataSource dataSource, String sql) {
    JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person> itemWriter = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();
    itemWriter.setSql(sql);
    itemWriter.setDataSource(dataSource);
    itemWriter
        .setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<Person>());
    return itemWriter;
    }
 @Bean
    JdbcCursorItemReader<Person> personReader1(DataSource dataSource, String sql) {
    JdbcCursorItemReader<Person> databaseReader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
    databaseReader.setDataSource(dataSource);
    databaseReader.setSql(sql);
    databaseReader.setRowMapper(new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Person.class));
    return databaseReader;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person> writer1(DataSource dataSource, String sql) {
    JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person> itemWriter = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();
    itemWriter.setSql(sql);
    itemWriter.setDataSource(dataSource);
    itemWriter
        .setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<Person>());
    return itemWriter;
    }

}

Main classes
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class CopyDbApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JobExecutionException, JobRestartException,
        JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException, JobParametersInvalidException {

    ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(CopyDbApplication.class, args);

    JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) ctx.getBean("jobLauncher");
    Job dbImportJob= (Job) ctx.getBean("DBImportJob");
    jobLauncher.run(dbImportJob, newExecution("DBImportJob"));

    }

    private static JobParameters newExecution(String jobName) {
    return new JobParametersBuilder().addDate("date", new Date())
        .addLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis())
        .addString("jobName", jobName)
        .toJobParameters();

    }
}
```

After executing this program, all the records are getting inserting into person1 table in DB3, person2 table in DB3 is not getting populated.

Excepted output :
person1 from DB1 -> person1 in DB3
person2 from DB2 -> person2 in DB3

Comment: Please share the configuration of your job repository. Which transaction manager do you use for each step?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine, thank you very much for your reply. I've updated complete program in the question. I'm using JpaTransactionManager

Comment: Thanks for the updates. However, I can't see from what you shared why data is correctly persisted in `person1` table but not in `person2`. If you share a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue, I can try to help.

Comment: I think, the problem is the same **personReader and writer** are shared with two steps.

Comment: I've **duplicated personReader and writer as personReader1 and writer1**. in the step2,_I set reader as personReader1 and writer as writer1_, then the application is working as excepted

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine, I've updated the completed program in the question. Can you please guide me, to refactor this program to avoid duplicate personReader and writer bean.

Comment: You can try to use `@StepScope` on the reader/writer and you will have an instance for each step (without the need to duplicate code).

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine, when changed the reader  to `@StepScope`  I got `org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.personReader' defined in class path resource [com/dbcopy/batch/config/LteCellJob.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'personReader' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.String' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}`

Comment: I've resolved the problem by adding  `@Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)` after @StepScope annotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following program will copy tables from two different db to single db(destination DB).
For Example,**Table1 from DB1 and to Table1 in the DB3 and Table2 from DB2 to Table2 in the DB3**.

```
 // Datasource Config
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "db3EntityManagerFactory",
    transactionManagerRef = "db3TransactionManager",
    basePackages = { "demo.sample.dao" })
public class Db3Config {

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "db3DataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create()
        .build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "db3EntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean db3EntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
        @Qualifier("db3DataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
    return builder.dataSource(dataSource)
        .packages("demo.sample.dao")
        .persistenceUnit("db3")
        .build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "db3TransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager db3TransactionManager(
        @Qualifier("db3EntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory db3EntityManagerFactory) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(db3EntityManagerFactory);
    }

}

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "db2EntityManagerFactory",
    transactionManagerRef = "db2TransactionManager",
    basePackages = { "demo.sample.dao" })
public class Db2Config {

    @Bean(name = "db2DataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "db2.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create()
        .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "db2EntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean db3EntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
        @Qualifier("db2DataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
    return builder.dataSource(dataSource)
        .packages("demo.sample.dao")
        .persistenceUnit("db2")
        .build();
    }


    @Bean(name = "db2TransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager db2TransactionManager(
        @Qualifier("db2EntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory db2EntityManagerFactory) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(db2EntityManagerFactory);
    }

}

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "db1EntityManagerFactory",
    transactionManagerRef = "db1TransactionManager",
    basePackages = { "demo.sample.dao" })
public class Db1Config {
    @Bean(name = "db1DataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "db1.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create()
        .build();
    }
     @Bean(name = "db1EntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean db1EntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
        @Qualifier("db1DataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
    return builder.dataSource(dataSource)
        .packages("demo.sample.dao")
        .persistenceUnit("db1")
        .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "db1TransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager db1TransactionManager(
        @Qualifier("db1EntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory db1EntityManagerFactory) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(db1EntityManagerFactory);
    }

}

-- Job Config

@Configuration
public class DBImportJob{

    @Autowired
    Db1Config db1Config ;

    @Autowired
    Db2Config db2Config ;

    @Autowired
    Db3Config db3Config ;

 @Bean(name = "DBImportJob")
    public Job dbImportJob(final JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory, final StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory) {


Step person1= stepBuilderFactory.get("Person1_FROM_DB1_TABLE")
        .<Person, Person>chunk(1000)
        .reader(personReader(db1Config.dataSource(),
            "select * from person"))
        .writer(writer(db3Config.dataSource(),
            "insert into person1"))
        .build();

    Step person2= stepBuilderFactory.get("Person2_FROM_DB2_TABLE")
        .<Person, Person>chunk(1000)
        .reader(personReader(db2Config.dataSource(),
            "select * from person"))
        .writer(writer(db3Config.dataSource(),
            "insert into person2"))     
            .build();


    return jobBuilderFactory.get("personImportJob")
        .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
        .start(person1)
        .next(person2)      
        .build();

    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    @Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    JdbcCursorItemReader<Person> personReader(DataSource dataSource, String sql) {
    JdbcCursorItemReader<Person> databaseReader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
    databaseReader.setDataSource(dataSource);
    databaseReader.setSql(sql);
    databaseReader.setRowMapper(new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Person.class));
    return databaseReader;
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    @Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person> writer(DataSource dataSource, String sql) {
    JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person> itemWriter = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();
    itemWriter.setSql(sql);
    itemWriter.setDataSource(dataSource);
    itemWriter
        .setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<Person>());
    return itemWriter;
    }

}

Main classes
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class CopyDbApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JobExecutionException, JobRestartException,
        JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException, JobParametersInvalidException {

    ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(CopyDbApplication.class, args);

    JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) ctx.getBean("jobLauncher");
    Job dbImportJob= (Job) ctx.getBean("DBImportJob");
    jobLauncher.run(dbImportJob, newExecution("DBImportJob"));

    }

    private static JobParameters newExecution(String jobName) {
    return new JobParametersBuilder().addDate("date", new Date())
        .addLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis())
        .addString("jobName", jobName)
        .toJobParameters();

    }
}
```